# AWS API Gateway on iOS

Tags: ios, json, amazon-web-services, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I am using NSURL to connect to my API Gateway and the response I recieve while on my iOS device is "Missing Authentication Token". I have checked that I have deployed my API. It is accessible and returns a fully filled out json via Chrome and Safari using the same url.

My Code:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://csjm26qn0c.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/truckstopsregion1/1"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"...NOT GOING TO SHOW..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"API-Key"];


NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(error == nil && data != nil){

        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    }
}];

[task resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with your API gateway access.

1. Your endpoint may not be set up to handle a `POST` request. Your URL returns data from a `GET` request. I change `POST` to `GET` and I am able to get JSON data. The "Missing Authentication Token" message is also a generic message for when the requested endpoint doesn't exist.
2. The JSON that is returned is malformed. Check the syntax. I have posted the JSON dictionary that I received from your URL. It is missing a comma at the longitude line.

   ```
   {
       "Stops" :
       [
           {
               "id"       : "1",
               "latitude" : "300",
               "longitude": "400"
               "name"     : "Test Stop 2"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Comment: Would suggest adding that the "Missing Authentication Token" message is a generic message for when the requested endpoint doesn't exist as well (your first bullet's case).

Comment: @AndrewTempleton Done :)

Answer (score 1):

ApiGateway can auto generate SDK's for iOS, Android, and JavaScript.  While this doesn't answer your question, using the auto generated SDK would (probably) solve the problem for you.

Take a look at the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-console